# Not able to assign elastic ip using knife

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef, knife

I want to create a EC2 instance using knife with an elastic ip assigned to it. Knife has the option --associate-eip but when I use this option it fails with error "ERROR: Elastic IP requested is not available." eventhough the EIP in AWS console shows the IP is available.

The command I executed

knife ec2 server create -S testKey -I ami-e7b8c0d7 --security-group-id test_sg -N test-eip -f m3.medium --region us-west-2 -i testKey.pem --associate-eip 6.6.6.6

ERROR: Elastic IP requested is not available.

Did I miss any obvious steps? 
Where does knife look for the elastic ip list? 
Is there a place to inform abt the elastic ip list to knife?

Answer (score 1):

After adding the --subnet attribute with the default subnetid of that region and adding --server-connect-attribute public_ip_address, its possible to create instances with eip assigned.

`knife ec2 server create -N test-eip -I ami-e7b8c0d7 --security-group-id sg-685a00d -f m3.medium --region us-west-2 --ssh-user ubuntu -S testKey -i key.pem --associate-eip 6.6.6.6 --subnet <default subnetid for that region> --server-connect-attribute public_ip_address`

To find the default subnetid of the region, launch the instance and in the "Configure Instance Details" take subnet id that is displayed.